# page not rendered when click on place order button

Tags: magento2

Magento 2 chekout page not rendered when clicking on place order button.
want to use an external payment gateway.

> **debug.log**
>   2018-10-10 08:01:56] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
>   [2018-10-10 08:04:37] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
>   [2018-10-10 08:05:02] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
>   [2018-10-10 08:05:19] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http://testing2.dukaania.com/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []

=================

> **system.log**
>   [2018-10-10 08:07:47] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
>   [2018-10-10 08:07:47] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
>   [2018-10-10 08:07:47] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
>   [2018-10-10 08:07:47] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'paypal.partner.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
>   [2018-10-10 08:07:47] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'bml.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
>   [2018-10-10 08:07:52] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
>   [2018-10-10 08:07:52] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
>   [2018-10-10 08:07:52] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
>   [2018-10-10 08:08:08] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/MageBig/martfury_layout01/en_US/MageBig_MbLib/js/jquery.nanoscroller.js.map' [] []

Here' my code

**/home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Test/Testpayment/view/frontend/web/js/action/set-payment-method-action.js**

/*jshint jquery:true*/

```
 define(
[
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/url-builder',
    'mage/storage',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader'
],
function ($, quote, urlBuilder, storage, errorProcessor, customer, fullScreenLoader) {
    'use strict';
    return function (messageContainer) {

         $url = 'http://testing2.dukaania.com/response_fail.php';
$.mage.redirect($url);//url is your url

    };
}
```

);

**/home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Test/Testpayment/view/frontend/web/template/payment/testpayment.html**

```
  <div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
<div class="payment-method-title field choice">
    <input type="radio"
           name="payment[method]"
           class="radio"
           data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()"/>
    <label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label"><span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span></label>
</div>
<div class="payment-method-content">
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <button class="action primary checkout"
                    type="submit"
                    data-bind="
                    click: placeOrder,
                    attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
                    css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()},
                    enable: (getCode() == isChecked())
                    "
                    disabled>
                <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up the method-renderer JS?

file like at location `/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/testpayment.js` in your case it will be a different file name.

check this - https://webkul.com/blog/redirect-to-third-party-link-after-order-place-magento2/

it is covering your stuff.

Comment: i m following this tutorial but nothing gonna happen page not rendered

Comment: can you provide your full module code here?

Comment: can we discuss in chat I sent u a link I uploaded on google drive?